# How do I specify the files I want CPack to pack into an RPM?

Tags: cmake, rpm, cpack

I'm making two rpms with CPack using its component feature. I want one to have .so files and the other to have all header files. I couldn't find any similar questions regarding packaging files in the component feature.

(DEVEL" is the component for my devel rpm)

Right now I have `set(CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_INSTALL_FILES path/../file1`

`...`

`path/../file2)`
just with all my files separated by returns but that does not work at all. What is the correct statement to provide a list of files I need in the rpm?

Currently it produces 3 rpms (I assume the third will just be a complete one with all files which I'm fine generating and not using). Two of the rpms have every file in the repo in them and the third just has two CMake files in it.

`cpack_add_component(DEVEL)`
`//Skipping version, description, name, setting source_dir...`
`set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)`
`set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_IGNORE_GROUPS 1)`
`set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_GROUPING ONE_PER_GROUP)`
`set(CPACK_COMPONENT_DEVEL_DISPLAY_NAME "devel")`
`set(CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_INSTALL_FILES "/usr/include/opentracing/noop.h`
...
`/usr/include/opentracing/version.h")`
`set(CPACK_COMPONENT_DIST_REQUIRED TRUE)`
`set(CPACK_COMPONENT_DEVEL_REQUIRED TRUE)`
`set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL DIST DEVEL)`

I am calling this from linux command line with `cpack -G rpm`

Comment: Hm, what about setting `CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL` variable to `ON`, so CPack will create RPM packages per-components?

Comment: I've had that ON and it creates 3 rpms. 2 of the rpms have every single file in them, and the third (devel) rpm only has two cmake files in it which were NOT intended to be in it.

Comment: Hmm, such rpms could be a problem. Could you provide your `CMakeLists.txt` (in form of [mcve]) which reproduce such behaviour?

Comment: `cpack_add_component(DEVEL)  
//assigned directories, version...  
set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)  
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_IGNORE_GROUPS 1)  
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_GROUPING ONE_PER_GROUP)  
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_DEVEL_DISPLAY_NAME "devel")  
set(CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_PACKAGE_NAME "opentracing-cpp-devel${OPENTRACING_VERSION_STRING}")
set(CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_INSTALL_FILES "/usr/include/opentracing/noop.h
...
/usr/include/opentracing/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp")  
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_DIST_REQUIRED TRUE)  
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_DEVEL_REQUIRED TRUE)  

set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL DIST DEVEL)`

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out formatting. The main thing that I can't figure out and can't find any documentation on is the CPACK_RPM_DEVEL_INSTALL_FILES call or some function similar to that that can modify what files are added to the rpm

Comment: Do not use comments for multiline code, add the code to the question post instead. You can format the code with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. Also, add to the code commands how to you install files/targets. They should have *COMPONENT* option set.

Comment: If you fail to figure out how to format, someone will be able to modify your post and format it. The content is more important. If you leave those out, no one will be able to help.

Comment: From what  I saw, installing targets applied to installing executables and libraries, and I didn't see how that worked with my rpm. Would I need an install target call with the component option? Still though, my main question is how to specify which files to include in the rpm...

Comment: You do not need to specify **for RPM** which files you want to pack. Instead, you need to assign *COMPONENT* option for every installed target or file. After that, CPack will automatically sort files, belonging to different components, to different RPM packages.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev , if you could briefly elaborate on how to assign COMPONENT option to a file that would be super helpful!

Comment: Every flow of [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) command accepts COMPONENT option. `install(FILES)` is not exception. Something like `install(FILES <header1.h> .. DESTINATION include COMPONENT HEADERS)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CMakelists.txt, add something like:

```
install(TARGETS outputfiles... RUNTIME DESTINATION bin LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

Then you can use

```
make package
```

in your build directory.